# Rounded corners for vector asset android studio

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to get a `.xml` vector asset to have rounded corners. I have the following code that's a flag, but with straight corners, and for a better visual effect I would need the corners to be rounded. I have tried to add `<corners ..... />` inside the `<path .. />` but there was no change

.xml :

```
<vector android:height="15dp" android:viewportHeight="15"
android:viewportWidth="21" android:width="21dp"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M0,0h21v15h-21z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient android:endX="10.5" android:endY="15"
            android:startX="10.5" android:startY="0" android:type="linear">
            <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF" android:offset="0"/>
            <item android:color="#FFF0F0F0" android:offset="1"/>
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
<path android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M10,0h11v15h-11z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient android:endX="15.5" android:endY="15"
            android:startX="15.5" android:startY="0" android:type="linear">
            <item android:color="#FFE5253D" android:offset="0"/>
            <item android:color="#FFCC162C" android:offset="1"/>
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
<path android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M0,0h7v15h-7z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient android:endX="3.5" android:endY="15"
            android:startX="3.5" android:startY="0" android:type="linear">
            <item android:color="#FF0A3D9C" android:offset="0"/>
            <item android:color="#FF042E7D" android:offset="1"/>
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
<path android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M7,0h7v15h-7z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">

        <gradient android:endX="10.5" android:endY="15"
            android:startX="10.5" android:startY="0" android:type="linear">

            <item android:color="#FFFFD955" android:offset="0"/>
            <item android:color="#FFFCD036" android:offset="1"/>
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this, if it could help as per your requirement:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="512dp"
android:height="512dp"
android:viewportWidth="512"
android:viewportHeight="512">
 <path
  android:pathData="M38.345,88.273C17.167,88.273 0,105.44 0,126.618v258.759c0,21.177 17.167,38.345 38.345,38.345h132.322V88.273H38.345z"
  android:fillColor="#FF0A3D9C"/>
<path
  android:pathData="M170.67,88.277h170.67v335.45h-170.67z"
  android:fillColor="#FFFFD955"/>
<path
  android:pathData="M473.655,88.273H341.333v335.448h132.322c21.177,0 38.345,-17.167 38.345,-38.345V126.618C512,105.44 494.833,88.273 473.655,88.273z"
  android:fillColor="#FFE5253D"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I suppose it's all about the `pathData` , right? Is there any tool that gives you that automatically considering your needs?

Comment: @costin yes you can use the Flaticon website (https://www.flaticon.com/). In this, you can found out several icons in SVG as well as in png format. And after that you can import that downloaded SVG icon in android studio and modify accordingly as per your requirement.